# Getting null in geocoder getSubAdminArea request however 10 days before it was returning a valid value

Tags: java, android, reverse-geocoding

I am using Geocoder for getting city, district and State name  in Android App based on java

```
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String district = addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea(0);
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
```

Before 10 days I was getting perfect results but now district value is null

I tried a lot and I think the problem is with the getSubAdminArea request because other requests are working properly please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

It suddenly stops working for me as well. For now, just to not break the functionality we have followed the alternative approach to get the Sub Admin area.
As an alternative, we can get the pin code of the area using getPostalCode() method and then, with the help of pin code , we can fetch the Sub Admin area.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your Idea sounds great can you please tell how you are fetching Sub admin area using postal code